# Evaluating a function call constructed from a string

Tags: r

Say I have two functions whose names are contained within a vector. I would like to test if each function works.

My approach, which I readily admit could be wrong, was to loop through the vector then paste `()` to the function name. But then I realized I have no idea how to evaluate the function call which is current stored as a string. Here is a reprex:

```
func1 <- function(){
  message("func1 works")
}

func2 <- function(){
  message("func2 works")
}

fv <- c("func1","func2")

for(i in seq_along(fv)){
  fv_func <- paste0(fv[i],"()")
  print(fv_func)
}
[1] "func1()"
[1] "func2()"
```

So in this context I am asking how to evaluate `func1()` and `func2()` though the ultimate goal is to evaluate function whose names are stored in a vector - meaning i'm open to better solution.

Comment: Also `eval(parse(text="func1()"))` will evaluate `func1()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the names of the functions as strings you can `get()` them:

```
fv <- c("func1","func2")

for(i in seq_along(fv)){
    fv_func <- get(fv[i])
    # Can just call normally, no need to paste () on
    fv_func()
}
```

Comment: or just `get(fv[i])()` - no need to assign

Comment: Also consider: `for(i in fv) match.fun(i)()` , which might be equivalent to `get()` in this simple case, but is nice to use inside other functions. See `?match.fun` for more info.

Comment: Also, not sure why the `seq_along` and indexing is needed. `for(i in fv) print(i)` will loop through neatly for example.

Comment: @thelatemail I've always been under the impression that indexing is always better and safer when looping in R.

Answer (score 2):

Try either of these:

```
out <- lapply(fv, do.call, list())

out <- lapply(fv, function(f) match.fun(f)())
```

Comment: I do like this answer a little better but I am unsure how to use it in my context. I am using this approach in a unit test and was the test each function evaluation in several ways. So having that assigned object is useful. No sure how to accomplish that with `lapply`.

Comment: Are you asking how to translate this to a for loop?  `for(f in fv) do.call(f, list())` and `for(f in fv) match.fun(f)()`

Answer (score 1):

We can do it in one line without a `for` loop if we use vectorised `eval(parse)`:

```
eval(parse(text = paste0(fv,'()')))
```